# How can I add exponent in my code

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator
{
    public static void main(String[] args )
    {
       Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
       String operator;
       double num1,num2,answer = 0;

       System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
       num1 = userInput.nextDouble();
       System.out.println("Enter operator: ");
       operator = userInput.next();
       System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
       num2 = userInput.nextDouble();

       if (operator.equals ("+")){
          answer = num1 + num2;
       }
       else if (operator.equals ("-")){
          answer = num1 - num2;
       }
       else if (operator.equals ("*")){
          answer = num1 * num2;
       }
       else if (operator.equals ("/")){
          answer = num1 / num2;
       }
       System.out.println("First number:" + num1);
       System.out.println("Operator:" + operator);
       System.out.println("Second number:" + num2);
       System.out.println("Answer: " + answer);
   }
}
```

Comment: Wut? Please actually explain your problem.

Comment: [`Math.pow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-)

Comment: I've to add the statement if the user wants to continue (y/n) in each operator. I'm new to this coding thing... can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function:

```
   Math.pow(x, y)
```

In this way: place the code

```
   else if (operator.equals ("^")){
      answer = Math.pow(num1, num2);
   }
```

just after your present code

```
   else if (operator.equals ("/")){
      answer = num1 / num2;
   }
```

So this part of code will then be

```
   else if (operator.equals ("/")){
      answer = num1 / num2;
   }
   else if (operator.equals ("^")){
      answer = Math.pow(num1, num2);
   }
```

Comment: where should I write this Math.pow (x,y)?

Comment: I've to add the statement if the user wants to continue (y/n) in each operator. I'm new to this coding thing... can you help me out?